# Prove or disprove that every Boolean function can be expressed by using only the operator ↓

Tags: induction

I know that the ↓ operator means "nor" but how do I prove/disprove that every Boolean function can be expressed using only this operator ? Induction ? Contradiction ? I have to idea where to begin. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Express and, or and not in terms of nor.

Comment: @copper.hat. Of course you realize that you only have to establish it for {and, not} or {or, not}.

Comment: @RickDecker: I realise that, I thought it would be more straightforward for the OP to use these and the Shannon expansion theorem.

Comment: @copper.hat. ... which is why I said "Of course you realize that...". Just being pedantic.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1**. Have you seen the algorithm that will express every Boolean function in [disjunctive normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_normal_form)? If you have, then you know that every Boolean function can be expressed using only $\land, \lor, \neg$ (and, or, not).

**Hint 2**. Since DeMorgan tells us that $p\land q\equiv \neg(\neg p \lor \neg q)$, we can express every Boolean function using only $\lor$ and $\neg$.

**Hint 3**. Show that $\neg p\equiv p\downarrow p$.

**Hint 4**. Using the above and the fact that $p\lor q\equiv \neg(\neg (p\lor q))$, find a way to express $p\lor q$ in terms of some expression in $p$ and $q$ and $\downarrow$.

Using these hints will give you what you want. Need some more help? Just ask.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: There are 16 binary Boolean functions to represent.  You need to represent all of them.